# Boolean aura attribute not working in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-attribute, winter24

I came across a weird behaviour on our sandbox org which is currently on Winter 24. We have several lightning components that we use in all different kind of screen flows.

For whatever reason aura attributes from the typ "Boolean" are no longer working - no matter which lightning component. Basically it is not expection true/false anymore. I played around with other types like "String" and "Integer" which work totally fine.

Here is an example attribute:

```
<aura:attribute name="showCurrentUserAccounts" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
```

and this is what it looks like in the flow when trying to access it:

[image]

What do I miss? I cannot reproduce this in production:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Well, looks like Salesforce just wanted to make a fool out of me. New day and it is working again...